# How can I set a named version on a Google Sheet programmatically?

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm used the google-sheets API to sync data to a sheet periodically. Sheets automatically retains versions which is great for backups in case my code trashes important data, and has the option to "only show named versions".

To make trawling versions easier, is there an API method which will let me set a named version in my code after making changes? I assume there is but cannot find it in the documentation so far.

Comment: metadata of that kind is handled by the Drive API - the Sheets API is more or less for data manipulation within the spreadsheet itself. Within the Drive API I don't believe you can name revisions, but you can (in theory) flag a revision to be kept forever. Whether that operation is allowed for nonbinary data like GSuite docs, I do not know. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions

Comment: As of June 2020, it's still not possible through the Google Sheets API, even in v4. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate The API response doesn't even give you any kind of revision ID for looking it up with the Drive API.

Comment: to Tessa comment: in 2021 it's still not available via Sheets API, but Drive API can be used to list revisions